# SortedSet with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, design-patterns, event-handling

I have something like this:

```
public class CPerson: INotifyPropertyChanged
public class CPeople: SortedSet<CPerson>
public class CMain
{
    private CPeople _people;
}
```

I want to know in `CMain` if something was changed in `CPeople`, new person was added or deleted or something was changed in some `CPerson` in `CPeople`, i have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `CPerson` but i don't have any brilliant idea what interface implement on `CPeople` class and how in good way get out `PropertyChanged` event over `CPeople` to `CMain`.

Can anyone help me?
Greetings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`ObservableCollection<Person>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). If you really need a SortedSet, you can also implement the  INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces yourself.

One way you could go forward could be to create your collection class wrapped around SortedSet, like so:

```
public class ObservableSortedSet<T> : ICollection<T>, 
                                      INotifyCollectionChanged, 
                                      INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly SortedSet<T> _innerCollection = new SortedSet<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Add(item);
        // TODO, notify collection change
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerCollection.Clear();
        // TODO, notify collection change
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _innerCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Remove(item);
        // TODO, notify collection change
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((ICollection<T>)_innerCollection).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    // TODO: possibly add some specific methods, if needed

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use SortedSet<> maybe you could create a descendant class (from SortedSet<>) that implements INotifyCollectionChanged. Or if you are not tied to SortedSet<> use ObservableCollection<> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own interface, `IPeopleChanged` etc, with events like `PersonAdded(Person p)`,`PersonRemoved(Person p)`,and something like `PersonPropertyChanged(Person p,PropertyChangedEventArgs arg)`, use the add method in your collection to subscribe your collection to the property change events from your items added to the collection, and bubble these along, and subscribe to the events in your collection in CMain.

So to sum up, your collection now has 3 events.one which fires when an item added,one when an item removed, and one that passes the PropertyChanged event along the chain when an item has changed.