# Custom collection that is observable-self sorting-prevents insertions etc

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, observablecollection

I have a custom type that knows how to compare with others (it implements IComparable), it is working great stored inside an ObservableList.

However there is still somethings lacking in the collection. I am in need of 4 features. A collection that :

1. Detects duplicates and prevents insertions.
2. Automatically sorts on every successful insert.
3. Is observable &
4. If batches of items are inserted only notifies once the batch is
   inserted.

I would like tips on how to make such a collection, what I will need to research/implement etc. I am not looking for code but if you can give that its a bonus.

What I have thought about doing :

Inheriting from ObservableCollection, overriding the add method, checking if the item already exists, if it does ignoring it.

Or

Implementing my own observable collection based off a more generic type like List.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is just as "generic" as `List`. No reason not to use it, if you want your collection to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. I think you should keep evolving your first idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you you want to prevent duplicate insertions and you want sorting, a [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) might be a good starting position. Since you want notifications, you'll have to extend the standard SortedSet and implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281607/187697) and another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268140/187697) which uses a `HashSet` instead (which is unordered, but you can easily replace with a `SortedSet`).

The alternative, which is just as valid, is to go with you first suggestion and extend `ObservableCollection`.